# Como calcular a soma de um grupo em MDX

Tags: business-intelligence, mdx, olap

Eu preciso criar um `Calculation` no SQL Server Data Tools.

Imagine que na minha estrutura OLAP Eu tenho as Dimensões Cidade e Revendedor, e uma Fato Vendas. Na dimensão Cidade eu tenho Cidade, Estado e a População, e essa População é uma medida em uma dimensão, tornando a dimensão cidade uma Fato e uma Dimensão ao mesmo tempo.

Eu preciso somar a População nas cidades das quais um revendedor teve vendas. Mas eu não consigo somar apenas a população das cidades com vendas, eu consigo apenas mostrar o total do estado. Lembrando que um vendedor pode vender em varias cidades e em mais de um estado.

Eu filtrei pelo revendedor John e a consulta retornou isso:

---

```
STATE  |   CITY            |     POPULATION 

CA     |   Los Angeles     |     10.000.000
CA     |   San Francisco   |      1.000.000  
CA     |   Sacramento      |      1.000.000   
CA     |   San Diego       |      1.000.000   
CA     |   Bakersfield     |        500.000 

Total                          37.000.000
```

---

A soma deveria retornar 13.500.000, mas para mim, a soma retorna 37.000.000, que é a população total da Califórnia.

---

O calculo que uso atualmente, é

```
SUM([Measures].[Population])
```

Eu não tenho conhecimentos avançados em MDX, Eu não consegui montar o calculo ainda apenas isso:

```
SUM(FILTER([Measures].[Population],[Sales Amount]>0))
```

ou isso

```
SUM(NONEMPTY((  [CidadesRadiografia].[Cidade].[Cidade],
                [Measures].[População],
                [RepresentantesRadiografia].[Representante].[Representante] )))
```

---

Resumindo, eu preciso retornar apenas a soma da população para as cidades que o revendedor teve vendas, mas atualmente ele mostra o total da população, por exemplo, se eu selecionar o pais e a cidade, retorna a soma do total do pais, e se eu selecionar o estado e a cidade, retorna a soma da população do estado.

---

Pregunta no [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637843/how-do-i-calculate-the-sum-total-of-a-group-in-mdx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agora após ler o livro **SQL Server 2008 MDX Step by Step** consegui montar um cálculo que está retornando o que eu precisava, ele está com ótima performance no SQL Server Management Studio e no Visual Studio Data Tools, porem no Excel não é muito performático, mas isso não vem ao caso. o cálculo MDX é o seguinte:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Populacao]

AS SUM(NONEMPTY((Filter([Measures].[População],[Measures].[Valor Total] >0), 
   FILTER([CidadesRadiografia].[Cidade].[Cidade],[Measures].[Valor Total] > 0)))), 

FORMAT_STRING = "#,##0;-#,##0;0;0", 
NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR = { [Valor Total] }, 
VISIBLE = 1;
```

Aconselho o livro acima para alguem que como eu nunca tinha trabalhado com MDX.